# Pine script version 2 to version 4 conversion identifier error

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to convert the below syntax from pine version2 to version4 but it gives an Undeclared identifier error as :

```
"line 17: Undeclared identifier 'ND_stretch'"
```

the syntax is as below:

```
ND_open = f_is_new_day(mode) ? security(tickerid, tf, open) : ND_open[1]
```

Please help me with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the history access operator `[]`, correct so:

```
ND_open = float(na) 
ND_open := f_is_new_day(mode) ? security(tickerid, tf, open) : ND_open[1]
```

Comment: line 15: 'ND_open' is already defined. This is the error I get. 
f_is_new_day(_mode) => _mode == 1 ? change(time(tf2))!=0 : _mode == 2 ? change(time(tf2, sess))!=0 : false
ND_open = f_is_new_day(mode) ? security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, open) : ND_open[1]
ND_high = f_is_new_day(mode) ? security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, high) : ND_high[1]
ND_low = f_is_new_day(mode) ? security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, low) : ND_low[1]
ND_stretch = na(ND_stretch[1]) ? 0 : f_is_new_day(mode) ? (ND_stretch[1]*9 + security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, (high-open)>=(open-low)?high-open:open-low)) / 10 :

Comment: Please provide a full script to investigate.